# Next.js Google provider not returning profile image (anymore)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using the Google provider in Next.js with Next-auth. I can successfully login, but I don't get the user profile image anymore. It was working fine before.
In the /api/auth/session call I can see the image is null:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "email": "xxx",
        "image": null
    },
    "expires": "2023-09-04T10:27:04.066Z"
}
```

I'm using prisma adapter, scope in DB seems to be ok:

```
openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Tried to remove the account en login again, but no success..
Any idea how to solve or debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently as well. I narrowed it down to being my organization managed profile that was not providing the `picture` url in the response. To resolve this I (being an admin in my Google managed organization) enabled the options for users to manage their own profiles (see [here for instructions from Google](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F7326921%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=7326921&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a)). I was then able to go to [my profile settings](https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info) and change my visibility to anyone which gave my application access to the account's profile picture.[image: Profile visibility setting]